# Где определяется переменная "Windows" в javascript от WinJS.1.0?

Tags: javascript

Есть программа, скачанная из магазина Майкрософт, проект 2013 года на WinJS.1.0. Запускаю локально. Почти всё основное работает, но одна переменная не определена - "Windows". Она используется в нескольких местах, например:

```
var a = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState; 
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation; 
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
```

Где определяется эта переменная "Windows"? Или чем её заменить?